# Sphinx can't find linuxdoc when building readthedocs project

Tags: python-sphinx, read-the-docs

I am creating some documentation using readthedocs.  I can make the html files locally, and when I open the html files with my browser the documentation looks exactly as I want it to.  So, I push the source to github and try to build the project there - but that fails with the following error:

```
Running Sphinx v4.1.2
loading translations [en]... done

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/compas-docs-readthedocs/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/registry.py", line 429, in load_extension
    mod = import_module(extname)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/compas-docs-readthedocs/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 953, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 965, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'linuxdoc'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/compas-docs-readthedocs/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/cmd/build.py", line 279, in build_main
    args.tags, args.verbosity, args.jobs, args.keep_going)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/compas-docs-readthedocs/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 237, in __init__
    self.setup_extension(extension)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/compas-docs-readthedocs/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/application.py", line 393, in setup_extension
    self.registry.load_extension(self, extname)
  File "/home/docs/checkouts/readthedocs.org/user_builds/compas-docs-readthedocs/envs/latest/lib/python3.7/site-packages/sphinx/registry.py", line 433, in load_extension
    err) from err
sphinx.errors.ExtensionError: Could not import extension linuxdoc.rstFlatTable (exception: No module named 'linuxdoc')

Extension error:
Could not import extension linuxdoc.rstFlatTable (exception: No module named 'linuxdoc')
```

I am using the linuxdoc.rstFlatTable module. I have installed linuxdoc locally and, as I mentioned, the local build of the html files works a treat, and the flat-tables appear as they should.  But the build at readthedocs fails.

I suspect I may need to set the path to linuxdoc in conf.py, but I don't know what the path is.

I installed linuxdoc thus:

```
pip install git+http://github.com/return42/linuxdoc.git
```

I can't find where it was installed.  Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dependencies like that must be explicitly added to your `requirements.txt` file,

https://docs.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guides/reproducible-builds.html#using-a-configuration-file

```
# File: docs/requirements.txt

# Defining the exact version will make sure things don't break
sphinx==3.4.3
sphinx_rtd_theme==0.5.1
readthedocs-sphinx-search==0.1.0
linuxdoc==20210324
```